# Finding three numbers that are pairwise not relatively prime, but with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, gcd-and-lcm

Find integers $ a,b, $ and $ c $ where $ \gcd(a,b,c) = 1 $, but $ \gcd(a,b)  \neq 1 $, $ \gcd(a,c) \neq 1 $, and $ \gcd(b,c) \neq 1 $.

I tried so many combinations but I can't find 3 integers that meet these requirements.

I even though $ (0,0,0) $ works, because I tried to convince myself 1 is the first positive integer where 0 has a divisor, because you can't divide by 0. I am not sure if there is a more systematic approach to this.

Comment: Hint: Try to imagine venn diagrams of prime factors

Comment: Thank you. I didn't really want an answer, I wanted a way to try and solve it myself.

Comment: No problem. Next time you can explicitly mention hints only

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider $a = 6, b= 10, c = 15$

An easy way to construct these is by considering three prime $2, 3, 5$, then pairwise multiply them.

Comment: Thank you very much for including the explanation. That is the "systematic" approach I was looking for :)

Comment: As an exercise try to construct $a, b, c, d$ such that $gcd(a, b, c, d) =1$, but pair-wise and triple-wise has gcd greater than 1. =)

Comment: a,b,c,d = (6,15,35,10)

Comment: Oh shoot, that didn't account for triple wise. heh

Comment: Hint: try turning your thinking on its head - rather than thinking about what will make each number share a factor with another number, think about the factors that should be missing (start with the example Jacky Chong gave you, then generalise).

Comment: An even easier way to construct these is to write a simple Python program and loop over a, b, c up to ~100 or so. O(100^3) = 1,000,000, which is back-of-the-envelope 10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any three prime numbers $p,q,r$ and create the products $pq,qr,pr$. Each product lacks one of the prime factors, so the largest number that divides all three is $1$, but every pair of products has a factor in common, and hence a gcd greater than $1$. This is a generalization of the rather specific answer given first.